# Group Low Search results by channel/collection?

Tags: low-search

I know I can make collections and search one or more of them using Low Search. If I understand correctly, the results I get back will be ordered by relevance. But what if I have several channels that I want to show in different lists on the search results page? Is it possible to group the results by channel? Within each group I would still like the most relevant results first.

To clarify my intention, my results page would have a few headings like 'people', 'news' and 'pages'. The people section would present the found entries from the 'people' channel with their picture, email address etc. while the news and pages entries would have their own look as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to order/group by collection in a single Results tag at the moment.

You could achieve something similar by having multiple Results tag on a page with different collection="" parameters.

Comment: Low, any chance this will be an upcoming feature? I wanted to group my results by collection as well and found this post in a search. Seems like it could be handy. Thanks!

Comment: It's not planned at the moment, because it's a lot trickier than you might think. Mostly due to the combination of native and non-native filtering. The current API EE provides simply doesn't account for it.

Comment: Thanks Low, one more quick question. The client asked for tis functionality but I'm goign to have to tell them no, so they will ask how they are sorted currently. I read this on Devot-ee..."Search results are sorted by relevance which is calculated through the use of MySQL’s native full-text functions" But I'm not sure what this means in laymen's terms. Can you describe how this works so I can pass it to my client? Thanks! And this is my first time using Low Search and it was great...wishing I would have used it in the past and will definitely use it in the future.

Comment: How MySQL calculates relevance is a bit of a mystery. It's a black box. Keywords and text go in, a score comes out. It's probably based on length of the text, amount of keywords present, where in the text it's present, etc.